# Ambiguous partial template specialization with variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11

For the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct IsOneOf<T,T> { const static bool True = true; };
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct IsOneOf<T,any_of<T,Ts ...> > { const static bool True = true;};
template <typename T, typename T2,typename ... Ts>
struct IsOneOf<T,any_of<T2,Ts ...> > {
  const static bool True = IsOneOf<T,T2>::True ||
                           IsOneOf<T,any_of<Ts ...> >::True;
};
template <typename T1, typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
struct IsOneOf< any_of<T1,Ts1 ...>, any_of<Ts2 ...> > {
  const static bool True = IsOneOf<T1,any_of<Ts2 ...> >::True &&
                           IsOneOf<any_of<Ts1...>, any_of<Ts2 ...> >::True;
};
```

The last specialization is intended to override the others, but I receive ambiguous template instantiation errors for `IsOneOf<any_of<int>,any_of<int,double,float>>::True`. Can someone suggest a way to overcome this?

Comment: Where's the base (non-specialized) template definition? It would also be nice to have `any_of` defined in the question, even if it is empty or incomplete as I suspect.

Comment: What's the point of this? Why not a simple recursive `IsOneOf<Args...>` ?

Comment: Hi, Casey, any_of is just a empty struct at this point. The purpose is to determine if one any_of group is a subset of another, i.e. any_of<short,int> should belong to any_of<unsigend int, int, unsigned short, short>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last specialization `IsOneOf<any_of<T1,Ts1...>, any_of<Ts2...>>` is not more specialized than `IsOneOf<T,any_of<T2,Ts...>>` because if `Ts2` is an empty list, it can't match the latter.  I think you want this, either in place of or in addition to your last specialization:

```
template <typename T1, typename ... Ts1, typename T2, typename ... Ts2>
struct IsOneOf< any_of<T1,Ts1 ...>, any_of<T2,Ts2 ...> >
{
    const static bool True = IsOneOf<T1, any_of<T2,Ts2...>>::True &&
                             IsOneOf<any_of<Ts1...>, anyOf<T2,Ts2...>>::True;
};
```

You would also have a problem with `IsOneOf<any_of<int,double>, any_of<int,double>>` since in that case your `IsOneOf<T,T>` is ambiguous with this general case.  So you can cut that off by specifying the intersection:

```
template <typename T1, typename ... Ts>
struct IsOneOf< any_of<T1,Ts ...>, any_of<T1,Ts ...> >
{
    const static bool True = true;
};
```

You will also need base cases dealing with the type `any_of<>`, if you don't already have them.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of this complicated and opaque design? If the idea was that `IsOneOf<A,B...>::value` is `true` if and only if at least one of the `B` types is the same as `A`, then a simple recursive design (avoiding auxiliaries such as `any_of`) such as

```
// is_one_of<A,B1,B2,...>::value == is_same<A,B1>::value || is_same<A,B2>::value ...
template<typename A, typename... B>
struct is_one_of;

// case of empty pack B...
template<typename A>
struct is_one_of<A> : std::false_type {};

// general case: recurse
template<typename A, typename B1, typename... B>
struct is_one_of<A,B1,B...>
: std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<A,B1>::value || is_one_of<A,B...>::value> {};
```

is preferrable, requiring only two specialisations (for an empty pack of `B`s and the recursive case). Moreover, `is_one_of` are good C++ citizens by being derived from `std::integral_constant<bool,C>`.